How relevant are older LaTeX textbooks?
I'm keen on getting learn LaTeX. However, most of the "recommended" books are quite old:

Guide to LaTeX by Kopka
Tikz and PGF
Math and more 4'th edition
etc

Many of them were written almost or more than a decade ago. From what I've looked at, LaTeX has been generally considered centralized to Overleaf (my current editor of choice). This might have made some of the content in the books "obsolete" in the eyes of relevant applications. So are the old books still considered relevant enough to compete with modern books written within a few years in the past?

Overleaf is a web interface with an editor for typing .tex-input-files and storing them at Overleaf instead of at your local machine. For compiling you can choose between various releases of the TeX distribution TeX Live and different TeX engines coming along with these TeX distributions. All this has nothing to do with the content of these books which are not about input editors and web interfaces for using a TeX distribution installed in a docker image at a remote server instead of at your local computer but are about writing documents using the TeX format LaTeX and macro packages for LaTeX.

As @UlrichDiez said, Overleaf is just an editor. Insofar as TeX is centralised, it is CTAN which is the centre of the TeX universe. LaTeX development has nothing to do with Overleaf. Overleaf just uses the software packaged by TUG as TeX Live and provided by the many people who contribute to CTAN. It's hard to think how it could be much less centralised. [FWIW I give students advice opposite to rallg: stick to pdfTeX unless you need unicode fonts.]

A decade? Practically an eternity! Seriously, though...one of the great things about TeX is that it still does the same thing today as it did 20 years ago (though perhaps not 40 years ago), so everything in the ten-year-old books will probably still work today, possibly with minor modifications.
For comparison, Microsoft Word was first introduced 40 years ago, and I swear they have introduced about three useful features (total) in the last 30 years, but learning Microsoft Word 6.0 won't help you at all learn today's version.

They are relevant, as you should know „the standard“. Many of its limitations were bypassed or overcome by packages over time. Without this practical background it‘s easy to get lost, puzzled and overwhelmed by LaTeX …

Even though the question put some focus on Overleaf, which is not relevant, as the previous comments stated, I believe that some things have changed in the TeX world. The biggest change is the stabilization of the Unicode engines (XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX), which is very important for multilingual typesetting. Moreover, packages gain new capabilities and new packages appear which do some things "better" (in whatever way) than older ones. So, the core is the same, but the way to do many things is evolving.

If you already own these books: Read them. If not: Search for newer books. Meanwhile there are a lot of good LaTeX introductions and also books for more, e.g., the new edition of TLC.

My personal favorite is a combination of the "Latex Companion" (which is about to appear in a new edition), tex.stackexchange -- and chatGPT. What I like about an old fashioned book is to browse through a large range of topics. An the new edition of TLC will be up to date for quite a long time, I guess.
